# Laravel's Authentication

Tags: laravel

I have an account called users. When a user logs in they view information specific to them. When another user logs in they view the other users information. What do I need to do to ensure logged in users only view their information only?

Comment: Code it accordingly? Read the docs at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authorization

Answer (score 0):

You can use $user = $request->user(); to get the user and return it as a variable with the view for the profile page. Then you can use the user variable to get the rest of the user's data.

Comment: Where should I use this $user = $request->user(); line of code? I am a newbie in laravel.

Comment: For example, in the profile controller, put it in the index functions and then pass it through the view as a variable. The return statement would look something like this: return view('profile/index', compact('user'));

Comment: Let me try this, in the mean time could you look at my controller and show me how I could implement it in there..

Comment: I have added the line of code but I have not achieved my goal.

Comment: You must pass the request into the function.  public function index(Request $request)

Comment: I did that and still did not achieve my goal.

Comment: In the home view, if the user and feedback are linked through a fk, then you should be able to access the feedback through $user->feedback, if you add the relation to the user and feedback models.

Comment: I added a foreign key on my complains table called user_id. In my profile controller I added this $user = $request->user(); and returned this return view('user.profile',$data, compact($user));. When I go to /profile/username the users still see each others information.

Comment: On that profile page, you should be able to access only the user's information. You access their information by using the relationship you declare in the model. You should be able to loop through the user's complaints/feedback by foreach($user->complaints as $complaint) and then use $complaint to access the information for the complaint.

Comment: When I do that I get this error : Call to a member function user() on string